# Issue using string literal types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use string literal types and getting an error. Can someone please explain why this error is happening and how to fix it?

If I change it to `type: string`, the error goes away.

```
export type Node = {
  name: string;
  type: 'root' | 'file' | 'folder';
  children?: Node[];
};

export function filterTreeByValue(tree: Node, inputValue: string) {
  function filter(node: Node): boolean {
    if (node.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
    }

    if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
      node.children = node.children.filter(filter);
      return node.children.length > 0;
    }

    return false;
  }

  const filteredTree = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tree)); // Create a deep clone
  filteredTree.children = filteredTree.children.filter(filter);
  return filteredTree;
}

const newTree = filterTreeByValue(treeContent, searchField); <-- type error is occurring here
```

Here's the error:

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; type: string; children: ({ name: string; type: string; children?: undefined; } | { name: string; type: string; children: ({ name: string; type: string; children?: undefined; } | { name: string; type: string; children: ({ ...; } | { ...; })[]; })[]; })[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"folder" | "file" | "root"'.ts(2345)
const treeContent: {
    name: string;
    type: string;
    children: ({
        name: string;
        type: string;
        children?: undefined;
    } | {
        name: string;
        type: string;
        children: ({
            name: string;
            type: string;
            children?: undefined;
        } | {
            name: string;
            type: string;
            children: ({
                ...;
            } | {
                ...;
            })[];
        })[];
    })[];
}
```

Here's a snippet of `treeContent`:

```
const treeContent = {
  name: 'Table of Contents',
  type: 'root',
  children: [
    { name: 'File 1', type: 'file' },
    {
      name: 'Folder 1',
      type: 'folder',
      children: [
        { name: 'File 1.1', type: 'file' },
        { name: 'File 1.2', type: 'file' },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Folder 2',
      type: 'folder',
      children: [
        { name: 'File 2.1', type: 'file' },
        { name: 'File 2.2', type: 'file' },
      ],
    },
    ...
    more lines here
    ...
  ],
};
```

Comment: What do you think the compiler thinks the type of `treeContent.type` is? Since you didn't annotate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
const treeContent = { 
  name: 'Table of Contents',
  type: 'root',
  children: [ ⋯ ]
};
```

the compiler [infers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) the type of `treeContent` from the initializing expression alone. It doesn't try to look ahead for subsequent references to `treeContent` when performing such inference.

There are lots of types compatible with a given expression and the compiler has to choose among them when inferring a type for the variable.  For example, the value `"abc"` could be seen as having the narrow string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"abc"`, or the wider [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"abc" | "def"`, or the wider type `string`, or the even wider [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `string | number`, or the incredibly wide type [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown), or anything in between.  How should it make the decision?  It ends up using heuristic rules that have been tweaked to give desirable behavior for a wide range of real-world use cases.

One such generally-desirable rule: a `string`-valued object property is inferred as the type `string`.  So if you write `const t = {type: "root"}`, the compiler will infer `t` as having type `{type: string}`.  It *could* choose `{type: "root"}` or `{type: "root" | "beer"}` or `unknown` or `{readonly type: any}` or lots of other things, but it chooses `{type: string}`.  Again, this is what most people expect and desire in most cases.

But heuristic rules are not foolproof and sometimes the type inferred by the compiler is not the one the developer wanted.  In your case, the `treeContent`'s `type` field is inferred as `string`, which is not compatible with `Node`.  So when it comes time to pass `treeContent` into `filterTreeByValue()`, there's an error.

---

Inference by the compiler is useful but ultimately we are in charge of the types.  When inference doesn't give us the types we wanted, then we cannot rely on inference alone, and must do something else.   So what should we do?

The most straightforward approach is that if you want a variable to be of a particular type, you should [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) it as such.  In your example, that would mean annotating `treeContent` as `Node`:

```
const treeContent: Node = { 
  name: 'Table of Contents',
  type: 'root',
  children: [ ⋯ ]
}; // okay
const newTree = filterTreeByValue(treeContent, searchField); // okay
```

That compiles without error; the compiler agrees that the initializing expression is compatible with `Node`, so there's no error in the assignment statement.  And since `treeContent` is now of type `Node`, the call to `filterTreeByValue()` also succceeds.

---

That might well be enough for your use case. But maybe you want to keep `treeContent`'s type a bit more specific than just `Node`, while still ensuring that it is *compatible* with `Node`.  If so, you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) instead of a type annotation.  This still lets the compiler infer the type of the variable, but provides [context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) that says to try to match it with `Node`:

```
const treeContent = { 
  name: 'Table of Contents',
  type: 'root',
  children: [ ⋯ ]
} satisfies Node; // okay

/* const treeContent: {
    name: string;
    type: "root";
    children: ()[];
} */

const newTree = filterTreeByValue(treeContent, searchField); // okay
```

That also compiles without error; the compiler agrees that the initializer satisfies `Node`, so there's no assignment error.  Furthermore the type of `treeContent` is inferred with a `Node` context, so the `type` property is inferred as type `"root"` instead of `string` (while the structurally similar `name` property is inferred as type `string` instead of `"Table of Contents").  So` treeContent`is of some object type that's assignable to`Node`, and thus the call to` filterTreeByValue()` succeeds.

---

And even those are not the only ways to proceed.  There are all sorts of ways you could affect the types.  You could write [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper functions to guide inference.  You could [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the value is of the type you want.  You could [`const`-assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) the initializing object literal to get very specific typings (but this would result in [`readonly` tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) for your array literals and you'd need to widen `children`'s type in `Node` from `Node[]` to `readonly Node[]`)  I won't make a long answer even longer by showing all of those.  The point is that you are ultimately in charge of the types of your values, and it's up to you to choose how to do so.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcByEAmqC8cDeAUHCXAHYCGAtsAFxwDOMUAlmQOYDcxpSK9AcigQIMAXAA+cAQDMWAG2DipsiPOxQB3UnADGACwWYowMgH56GbAG0AutwC+3QqEiw4MgK5ldMFhDIPBRhgKAAVE2AAIUQANQp5T2AACmZgOnQsYAAaODYwTxh4xIymVg4ASgIeEi8fPwCg+RCoZLIsyyyK+gAjEUUKQKIdHRYZODasgDpKGimYCAAZCAB3UIBhCgYUiqm2XUTsBmT8wuKk+aXVja2diqrhkaeTGE8oQOYk7Se4B0IakZjCbtbBTAxGEyBABkUPI03B6khU0UHBg+jgAD44AAGB4An5w0EI4ymOB4EHAMGGRGmKZyZqhZL0loVb4EkgvN6BClUiG0lHsNGYnFskZ-fGkTnvDwJbai8U6XQBJhNFrATARdJkuAAKQAygB5NBTMAUKDbZL6o1TMpsdhjRCpSL3ThwAD0brg6xMFBCcAocGwwDAenkAWAAOZoXVmspxMh2qjJg1kV5NLIdOCjKTrIBUsCSZjkUc-1mwAYpt0qANEDADGqiuV8DSwHWARCZHgeEeTzLgjCFB6ijgEHGbc7phgDAE2QlJD4GSEIjEs4J8dM9Gsc5G+HI1EXADEFKgAIwzhDIRf0pS-Vfskg9++kPvSA9qDRwM93p+8S+CGTvqEM7bmu1IkmQm4gU+u4vgIR7DieUxfhe-DSNe4gON+P47nuNCCPBp5TAATOeC7-seGFYT+thUT8mFQQ+DEjLBb7qKEcAkbR95kWhgGaFx7LrhBcBbthPwwfu+HHhxSGkX+aEUbeTEEhJeGvtJRHEXJqGyIp9FiSQNFMfR25GToTgAkqZAqtsZoGEewDqNqABEzmWU25DACssaJlm4SRDE5wpC244djAuS2VA9ksI5mC5n8ZYVhQVZwAAgmQ7QwL6qCPlZKohe2k6dNg2qPjosEDkOqCjl6hWdtOAk8UuojAaBfLCaJ0G4Ye0nIU16FKT+ZVPixfGfq1Bn9XxE1iUJkEGThLG9bJuT9XpAlDd1UkIVpq3ybpiiUcppBmU++nQcdJCjWxUAcTN2FTTd90-nNImXYtknqcOml9ftA3nQtD5bV9qCaZxKFXut72nfeJkEjDvzudZ8CRdFsUuW5jbI553mRL5DL+ekgUJEkTrpKFk4RcAdn6A56jxf8hCJZWqB6r6LAMHI5YNqQeXNpEFOdqV24VYOw41YLU7Pb+OnCC1AmvZ196qT1CHaZDh2DRdC3XR+X7vY9GjS-eivvToKvbYRv06f9G1dUtO3g2tmsA9hCMEq7Knvbr7GcQbf3TXbTym4DpAWyDMnWxrN6ewZ4dwRpu0Q+RLtByM7t0bOplYQ4jDs5zMX1lYwCim6ABUegeQVE6dvQw1XZ9tocKKOg8c5cswM5Le82BkL0MkFR2PKcBl26jNYzZ1NRbTMVOXgrlIyqZBeT5eBJrGxMlGTrZ1eFjBT2j9Mlkz+5JSl45MKlDDbO4j6uNAzaXpkJXdiLjfMHa3fzvtHfKApmsqAAk9L+ehe6mAsHAH0mAAjyEQM-YAQ8AQWQBPfdwdRfD+ALH5DecQSbBUiMVHIeQyAFCKHg+gTd2B4gJOghoWCCaTGwIQ7ocA+hqGpkMJiQJGGUjLJcZYawoCbAtLsfYhxywnBIWcPB-DrhCNuAPe4PMxL5gQFAL4xl-g-m4TyIScAYSEjjGAjMAohRYlxMo7CujjHamse1TMDCcwgIJKoux6ZkSmEFOicxzjSAKifKomQsoS7bn8cHDyhYUxajwFaY0ppzQpFiTaD+HAHTbxdO6T03pqZ+gDEGEMBxwzbkibGNM4F8ZqiiUY+xSYmR+VzC44ArxpQlOLEgrRvMq4C13sLAkosqojjHLvBq24mq-wVsY+a9tPoJzVntG2UMhrexmaxPWxt2SGyAmnRUky3qhyBg7K26sU4x22eJYGszCJOz+osgyGcnixyePXdkPtbp+wWps-i70Q77PjgRSOxz-6nLNmHC5-ywaAoOsCha9yxRZ3hjnf09Y+bOEXijA+M90bz0xp07Gy9cbRNVKEHBQVt6SypjTOmcVHBAA)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It was very helpful!